# Ubuntu Software Center erratic behavior in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: software-center, 21.04

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 20.10 to Ubuntu 21.04.
Presently there are two software centers on my system, as you can see here:
[image]

If I left-click on "Ubuntu Software", nothing happens: the application does not launch.

If I right-click on "Ubuntu Software" and I select "Show details", the application launches, albeit showing a message "Sorry! There are no details for that application" (but at least it starts)

The expected behaviour would be that, when I clic on the icon, the application starts...
Any suggestions ?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe ubuntu 20.10 software center icon doesn't deleted and they was stay in list but they don't have any data it's just icon.

Comment: Why you say that every where????

Comment: @Am.Shekari no, as I wrote, if I rightclick it and hot "show details" the app opens. It' just left-clicking that doesn't open it. What do you mean "Why you say that every where???? " ?

Comment: some one in comments says "this is your question(and paste another question link)" but when I go to another question I see he paste it there too so I say "why you say that every where???"

Comment: and please take screen shot of "show details" and paste it in question